# How to create hook for CMS Block in prestashop

Tags: content-management-system, hook, block, prestashop-1.6

I need to create hook for CMS block individual content in prestashop. So that i can display CMS items in different positions and also i need to display CMS items in home page.

Is it possible to create hook for CMS block. Any suggestions would appreciate

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use displayTop hook through a custom module and need to change the rendering condition for different pages of PrestaShop.

Every page in PrestaShop has a unique name that can be used to change block content as per your requirements.

The page name can be fetched using following line in any Class file in PrestaShop:

```
$this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['page_name']->value
```